# Varchar from textarea without line breaks

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a problem with textareas in my php project because in each textarea I can write a text with enters and save the value of `textarea` in a `varchar` field.

My problem Is when I load the text from database it shows me all text in same line and I don't understand why. With no breaks.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: [look at `nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Comment: or use `textarea { whitespace: pre; }` in CSS if the issue is when loading the string back into your editor.

Comment: why are you not using ckeditor?